# Running Bash Script in Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal, usb

So essentially, I am trying to run the command "/dir/command -arg" to change the LED color on a USB device in Java. I am using Ubuntu 10.04. When I run the command from the terminal, it works just fine.

However, I tried every iteration of Runtime.exec() that I could find and none of them seem to work. I then created a script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
/dir/command -arg
```

when I run this from a terminal it works just fine. However when I run

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String[] lookupCmd = {"/bin/sh","-c", "sh /dir/script.sh"};
    try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process lookupProc = runtime.exec(lookupCmd);
      lookupProc.waitFor();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lookupProc.getInputStream()));
      String line = reader.readLine();        
      while (line != null) {
        id.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
```

"hello" print but nothing else. There is no error.

My other command should not yield any output, but simply change the color of an LED. However when I run it with the same command but a different arg which yields an ouput, it still only prints "hello".

I also made sure that my user has permissions to the /dev folder with the usb device.

Comment: how you have made sure that your user has permissions to the /dev folder with the usb device ??

Comment: So originally I was getting "libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/003: Permission denied." so I went to "/dev/bus/usb" and used chown to change the owner of everything within that folder to my user. This is the same user that appears if I use "gnome-terminal" in Java.

Comment: how can you say there is **no error** when your are not implementing `error stream`

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795145/capture-error-from-runtime-process-java/11795368#11795368)

Comment: Derp, my bad. Yeah, I was not setting an environment variable. Thanks!

Comment: @user145181 If you got it working go ahead and add an answer with what you did (so people can see what you did), and accept it.

Comment: Mmk, will do. Because I'm a new user it says I need to wait 8 hours to do, so I'll probably do it tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't running the error stream, so I've added that.

After that I realized I was missing an environment variable, so added:

```
String[] envar = {"VAR=path"}
```

and called:

```
runtime.exec(lookupCmd, envar);
```

Works great now.